# When click on menu item, change the body style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We need to do so that when you click on the main menu items, changed both style BODY, by default (body class = "front") front, but when you click on the menu, design, class will not front but work, when you click on the menu pretul (body class = "pret"), etc.

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="limbi" />

  <h1 id="site-name"><a href="/">web site</a></h1>
  <nav>
<!--
THIS MENU
-->
    <ul class="main-nav" >

     <li class="careers"><a href="/ro"><span class="menu-item-title">HOME</span></a>
</li>
<li class="work"><a href="/ro/design"><span class="menu-item-title">DESIGN</span></a>
</li>
<li class="pret"><a href="/ro/pret"><span class="menu-item-title">Pretul</span></a>
</li>
<li class="promovare"><a href="/ro/promovare"><span class="menu-item-     title">Promovare</span></a>
</li>
<li class="port"><a href="/ro/portofoliu"><span class="menu-item-title">Portofoliu</span></a>
</li>
<li class="contact"><a href="/contact"><span class="menu-item-title">Contacte</span>   </a>
</li>

     </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a class name of elements, you can use these Jquery methods.

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

```
var body = $('body');
body.removeClass('front').addClass('design');
```

Comment: Hi, i'm a very little programmer.... i don't understand this, you can write all how i do it directly in html file?